# Robot Framework how can I search deeper into the webelement list

Tags: python, robotframework

In python I can do something like this:

```
List = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "locator")
for element in List:
    el = element.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "other locator")
    ...
```

My question is, can I do something like this in the Robot framework?

Answer (score 0):

There is no builtin function for this in RobotFramework. What you could do is make your own function in python and use it in RobotFramework as keyword. Here's a guide on how to accomplish that. https://robocorp.com/docs/development-guide/robot-framework/how-to-use-custom-python-libraries-in-your-robots

Answer (score 0):

using robot framework browser library you could do something like this, i have not tested it but it seem plausible

```
@{elements} =    Get Elements    ${locator}
FOR    ${element}    IN    @{Elements}    
    ${el}=    Get Element    ${other_locator}
...
```

Comment: This does not start locating from the initial elements node and thats what OP is trying to accomplish.